# SQL - Need to insert data from one table into another where 1 field equals another

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Not sure if this is a basic question or not but I can't seem to figure out the syntax.

I have one table called `leads` - primary key `LeadsId` and another table `rep_assign` with prime key `lead_id`.

I want to store `rep_id`, which is a field located in `rep_assign`, in to the `leads` table where `leads.LeadsId = rep_assign.lead_id`.

Anyone know how?  I just want to move the data from one table to another where `LeadsId` is equal to `lead_id`.

I've tried `SELECT INTO` and `INSERT INTO` a couple of ways but I can't seem to get it to work.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: what's the relationship between Leads Table and Rep_assign Table? OneToOne, OneToMany etc?

Comment: OnetoOne - leads.LeadsId = rep_assign.lead_id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like both of your tables already have most of the data in them. Perhaps you just need to update the leads table to add the rep_id.

```
UPDATE leads SET rep_id=(SELECT rep_id FROM rep_assign WHERE rep_assign.lead_id=leads.LeadId ORDER BY rep_assign_id DESC LIMIT 1)
```

N.B. subqueries like this work in most RDBMSs, but not all. If this doesn't work for you, it would help if you could tell us what RDBMS you're using (e.g. MySQL).

Comment: I ran this and it said 'unknown column leads.LeadsId in where clause' - makes no sense LeadsId is used throughout the program. It is a MySql DB.

Comment: Sorry mistyped the original query. Now when I run the above it reads 'sub query returns more than 1 row'. ??

Comment: You can easily put a LIMIT 1 in the subquery, but it sounds like there's a bigger problem with your data.
Is it possible to have multiple records with the same lead_id in your rep_assign table? If so, how do you intend to know which rep should be copied across to the leads table?
The query can definitely do what you want, just help me understand how you want it.

Comment: if these tables are OneToOne, @JeremyLawson query should work.

Comment: Okay that worked. It's possible to have multiple records with same lead_id in rep_assign table however unlikely. There is a rep_assign_id that is unique in the rep_assign table. Is there a way to take the rep_id with the greatest rep_assign_id since that would be the newest record or is that what the above query does?

Comment: I have modified the query to get the newest rep_id, and to include the LIMIT 1 which you had to use to overcome the OneToMany relationship.